# Where we can see the MySql database table and stored values from Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, mysql, iphone, database

I am developing a simple iPhone app for Apple Push Notification. I followed the below link http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2. I have downloaded the MySql from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg and downloaded in my mac. And `RayWenderlich gave us a php and sql file for the project` i have downloaded the `PushChatServer folder from the above raywenderlich site`. I this folder i found `database.sql, api.sql and push.sql`. Now i want to check whether the entered values store in the database tables or not.

How and where can i check the table and stored values from the Mac OS X v10.6.8? Can anyone please help me to found the solution? Thanks in advance.

Here is the table details

```
api.sql = CREATE TABLE active_users
database.sql = CREATE DTATABASE pushchat DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
push.sql = CREATE TABLE push_queue
```

Please help me.

Comment: you are install mamp for your mac system?

Comment: No i didn't use MAMP i just downloaded MySql in mac and used the PushChatServer sql files in my project/Mac? Is this is wrong?

Comment: you can download MAMP best Manage and viewing SqlTables design view,because,otherwise your mysql view table only command prompt using database query..!

Comment: My client wants own server setup so only i ignored MAMP and tried to setup a own server. Can you please tell how to check the table and stored values from mac? Thanks.

Comment: you can read this post http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-command-to-show-list-of-databases-on-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download one software using that yo can see your all database or table data download sqlite manager dmg file and install in your mac.

http://sqlitemanager.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: Dinesh If it is helpful for you inform us.

Comment: Mr.Vishiphone Thanks for your answer. Am used MySql database in my project you have preferred SQLite Manager. can i check the table and values from SQLite manager? Can you please clarify my doubt? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mr.Gopinath using that you can check your database and check your before added data and and your updated data also.Because I am Using this Only.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification Vishiphone. I will check it and let know you the result. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Your welcome and please tick the right mark on answer if you solve your problem so it will be helpful for other Thanks.